# Changing picture moving the line (js)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a div that contains two pictures (for example, a square and a round as shown in the picture); and a movable vertical line that will cut one image and reveal another. How do I do this in JS/jQuery?

[image]

Comment: http://www.catchmyfame.com/catchmyfame-jquery-plugins/jquery-beforeafter-plugin/

Comment: @Zealander thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be easily can be done by using .draggable jquery function:

```
$('.divider').draggable({
  axis: 'x',
  drag: function(e, ui) {
    $('.right').width(100 - ui.position.left);
    $('.yellow').css('right', ui.position.left);
  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOvVjd